# Trying to resolve value error: invalid mode in Python script

Tags: python, filepath, mode

I am trying to resolve a value error: invalide mode. Here is a snippet of my script where the error occurs (see line 49). All suggestions welcome! Thank you:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-a42f00b78742> in <module>
     47 output_file = Path("Users\steve\homework\PyBank\PyBank_data.csv")
     48 
---> 49 with open(output_file,"Users\steve\homework\PyBank\PyBank_data.csv") as file:
     50 # Write methods to print to Financial_Analysis_Summary
     51 

ValueError: invalid mode: 'Users\steve\homework\PyBank\PyBank_data.csv'
```

Comment: The docs: [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 0):

The `open` function is interpreting your file path as a mode argument. Have a look at the description of the function here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Basically, the first argument should just be the file path, and the second argument should be a string describing how you want the file to be open; try 'r' to start and read the documentation to understand the other mode arguments

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `open()` must be the file name, the second a mode-string like "r+" or "w". In your code, you're giving the file name twice. I think the error message you get is very clear on this.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to second parameter (Check the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

```
open(file, mode='')
```

You need a param with the mode to work with a file

```
open("Users\steve\homework\PyBank\PyBank_data.csv", mode='r')
```

or something like that

Comment: @tdelaney you need add the mode required depending on your function.
Example: mode='r' open for reading (default)

See all the options here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0):

You're supplying the filename twice in `open(output_file,"Users\steve\homework\PyBank\PyBank_data.csv")`

You want either `open(output_file)` or `open("Users\steve\homework\PyBank\PyBank_data.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to fetch some records from a excel file. You can try this:-

```
 with open("c:\\Users\steve\homework\PyBank\PyBank_data.csv") as file:
       contents = file.read()
```